# What is wrong with my threaded programming?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

There is an efficieny issue with my thread programming where I try to simulate producer-consumer schema.

Phase1's output is phase2's input.

The problem is when I run phase 1 and phase 2 independently, I have efficient results in terms of time that it took to execute.

But when I run threaded fashion it took x1000 times longer to execute.

This is my main module for threaded programming:

```
#Phase1 is producer
phase1_thread= Phase1Thread()

phase1_thread.daemon=True
phase1_thread.start()

# Phase 2 is consumer
phase2_thread = Phase2Thread()
phase2_thread.daemon=True
phase2_thread.start()

import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is phase 1 (producer):

```
global queue
self.Phase1= phase1()

input= ....
for i, batch in input.groupby(np.arange(len(input)) //1000):
    #print(i)
    tuple_of= self.Phase1.extract(batch,i)
    output=tuple_of[0]
    queue.put(output)
    time.sleep(random.random())
```

This is phase 2 (consumer)

```
self.Phase2 = phase2.EntityResolver()
global queue
global stream_count
global thread_processed
counter=0
while True:
    tuple_of = queue.get()
    input=tuple_of[0]
    queue.task_done()
    self.Phase2.run(input)
    counter=counter+1
    time.sleep(random.random())
```

Comment: So which is your question:  What is wrong with the logic?  or  Where is the inefficiency?

Comment: Sorry about confusion, I'm asking where is the inefficieny?